# Redux/React/Material-UI State Synchronization

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, material-ui

I've got an application that pulls user information from my database to fill out a "settings" dashboard for each user. The problem that I'm having is that the way I'm integrating React Hooks and Redux.

My structure is three layers deep. At the bottom is a Material-UI switch that changes the state to on/off. It looks like this:

```
const MySwitch = (props) => {

  const handleChange = event => {
    props.setState(event.target.checked);
  };

  return (
    <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <FormControlLabel
          control={
              <Switch
                  checked={props.state}
                  onChange={handleChange}
                  inputProps={{ 'aria-label': 'secondary checkbox' }}
                  color="primary"
              />
          }
          label={props.label}
      />
    </MuiThemeProvider>
  );
};

export default MySwitch;
```

That switch recieves the setState and state values from the settings page, which is simply an array of such switches. That settings array gets the initial state from my server, using the connect-redux function that's available. It looks like this:

```
function Settings(props) {

    const [isFara, setIsFara] = useState(props.fara);
    const [isSenators, setIsSenators] = useState(props.senators);
    const [isSenateCandidates, setIsSenateCandidates] = useState(props.senateCandidates);

    useEffect(() => {
        props.startToggleFara({ fara: isFara, id: props.id, token: props.token })
    }, [isFara]);

    useEffect(() => {
        props.startToggleSenators({ senators: isSenators, id: props.id, token: props.token })
    }, [isSenators]);

    useEffect(() => {
        props.startToggleSenateCandidates({ senateCandidates: isSenateCandidates, id: props.id, token: props.token })
    }, [isSenateCandidates]);

    return (
        <div className="settings">
            <div className="setting_switch">
                <Switch 
                    label={'Foreign Lobbyists'}
                    state={isFara}
                    setState={setIsFara}
                />
            </div>
            <div className="setting_switch">
                <Switch 
                    label={'Senators'}
                    state={isSenators}
                    setState={setIsSenators}
                    className="setting_switch"
                />
            </div>
            <div className="setting_switch">
                <Switch 
                    label={'Senate Candidates'}
                    state={isSenateCandidates}
                    setState={setIsSenateCandidates}
                    className="setting_switch"
                />
            </div>
        {!props.fara && !props.senators && !props.senateCandidates && <p className="warning">You have no alerts set up.</p>}
        </div>
    );
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    id: state.auth.id,
    fara: state.settings.fara,
    senators: state.settings.senators,
    senateCandidates: state.settings.senateCandidates,
    token: state.auth.token
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    startToggleFara: ({ fara, id, token }) => dispatch(startToggleFara({ fara, id, token })),    
    startToggleSenators: ({ senators, id, token }) => dispatch(startToggleSenators({ senators, id, token })),
    startToggleSenateCandidates: ({ senateCandidates, id, token }) => dispatch(startToggleSenateCandidates({ senateCandidates, id, token })),
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Settings);
```

The switches correctly update the values in my server when clicked, meaning they fire off the actions. However, when I navigate away from this component and refresh it, the props are not being passed down to the switches, which are defaulting to 'false'.

For some reason, that is then triggering the redux actions bound to the handleChange prop on each switch (which are passed down as startToggleFara, startToggleSenators, and startToggleSenateCandidates) which is then dispatching the actions and turning each of the settings in my server to 'false'.

**How can I connect these switches to my Redux store so that when the component loads it correctly pulls in the state from redux, and is capable of modifying that state as well?**

Comment: Have you considered bumping react-redux to v7 so you can use their hooks to access the redux store rather than using local component state for global application state concerns?  https://react-redux.js.org/next/api/hooks

Comment: While I could, my whole architecture is built around the current system and was wondering if there's something wrong about the current props/state flow that I could fix.

Comment: When do you pull the server's data to use as the initial values?